# Finding the size of a grapheme cluster in Rust

Tags: rust

I am working on a scanner (or tokenizer or lexer if you prefer). I must iterate through a string slice. I have found two methods for doing so that work:

**First**, I can create an iterator and iterate through each character. Here is a simplified example:

```
let s = "чеllo".chars();
for c in s {
    println!("{}", c);
}
```

However, if I want to look ahead it is a little less straightforward:

```
let mut s = "чеllo = ==".chars().peekable();
loop {
    match (s.next(), s.peek()) {
        (Some('='), Some(&'=')) => { s.next(); println!("==") },
        (Some('='), _        )  => println!("="),
        (Some(c)  , _        )  => println!("{}", c),
        (None, _) => break,
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that I can do multiple peek aheads if I want to, for example, look at the next next character.

So I can instead work on the **second** method. I can convert the string slice to a vector of chars. For example:

```
fn char_at(text: &Vec<char>, pos: usize) -> Option<char> {
    if pos < text.len() {
        Some(text[pos])
    } else {
        None
    }
}

let mut text = "чеllo = ==".chars().collect();
let mut position: usize = 0;
loop {
    match (char_at(&text, position), char_at(&text, position + 1)) {
        (Some('='), Some('=')) => { position += 1; println!("==") },
        (Some('='), _        ) => println!("="),
        (Some(c)  , _        ) => println!("{}", c),
        (None     , _        ) => break,
    }
    position += 1;
}
```

What I'd like to try now is a third method that is a bit of a cross between the two. Essentially, what I want is the [char_at](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.1.0/syntax/str/fn.char_at.html) method that Rust had before and I want the ability to get the size of a grapheme cluster.

If I had those two features, I could use a method similar to my vector of characters method, but I could do so directly on the string slice. Something like this (**this is not valid Rust code**):

```
let mut text = "чеllo = ==";
let mut position: usize = 0;
loop {
    let next_char = text.char_at(position);
    let peek_char = text.char_at(position + next_char.len());
    match (next_char, peek_char)) {
        (Some('='), Some('=')) => {
            position += peek_char.len();
            println!("==")
        },
        (Some('='), _        ) => println!("="),
        (Some(c)  , _        ) => println!("{}", c),
        (None     , _        ) => break,
    }
    position += next_char.len();
}
```

Note: what I want is for `next_char.len()` and `peek_char.len()` to give me the number of bytes that those graphemes comprise.

Here is my understanding of the approaches above:

- The iterator approach makes it difficult to perform multi-peek.
- The vector approach is a bit more costly (O(n) time to create vector and it requires more memory). Neither of these costs are overly significant, but I'm trying to learn better approaches.
- The third approach that I've discussed introduces methods that would cause nightmares for those of us that are not unicode experts.

I'm brand new to Rust. So these are my questions:

- Am I missing a completely alternative approach?
- Is there an easy way to add multi-peek to an iterator?
- Can my third approach be implemented using functionality of which I am currently unaware?

Comment: Could you use existing parsing libraries [like `nom`](https://github.com/Geal/nom)? You declare the grammar and it will generate a parser for you that can handle these lookahead issues.

Comment: @kennytm: Not sure if nom has the concept of grapheme cluster... but then I am not quite sure the OP needs grapheme clusters to start with.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The `char` type OP using can only represent a code point. I think OP is confusing that "one char ⇒ multiple UTF-8 code units" with "one grapheme cluster ⇒ multiple chars".

Comment: @kennytm I could use a library, but this is mostly a learning exercise and I'd like to know if what I proposed is possible. I could definitely be misunderstanding the terminology. What I'd like to know is how can I replicate the unstable "char_at" method, and how can I figure out how many bytes comprise the current character.

Comment: @MatthieuM I might not.

Comment: @drajc: To be honest, I just have strictly no idea what you're attempting to do here. So let's clarify terminology first: Unicode has the concept of Code Points and Grapheme Clusters. A Code Point is represented by a numerical value such as `U+1F4A9` (the  emoji), Rust calls it `char`. Grapheme Clusters are combinations of multiple Code Points which merge together to represent a single (complex) entity: combining the code point U+0065 (e) and U+00B4 (´) produces a grapheme cluster (é). It seems to me that you do not care at all about those, and just want multi-peek instead.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for the explanation! My understanding was off (I thought code point was always a single byte and that characters comprised multiple code points--you've clarified a few things for me with your example). 

Is it possible to get the number of bytes for a single code point (or grapheme cluster if two code points should be combined) that I can index in the string slice? (I'll update my question with a better example).

Comment: @drajc: If you only deal with code points, the `chars()` iterator iterates over code points, so `chars().peekable()` allows you to see both the current (popped) and next code point. You don't even have to do it yourself.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Is there a standard way to peek two characters (or any number) ahead with a peekable iterator? Also, for your example, will `chars()` treat the U+0065 and U+0301 as two separate characters or will it combine them?

Comment: @drajc U+0065 and U+0301 will appear as two consecutive `char`s. You cannot fit two code points into one `char` value, and `chars()` produces one `char` at a time.

Comment: @drajc: If you want to see multiple elements at a time, you could use the `windows(n)` iterator which is a sliding window of length `n` over the underlying slice. You cannot match on the returned slice though. Otherwise, I advise you to have a look at [`itertools`](https://github.com/bluss/rust-itertools); notably it `tuples` iterator.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for teaching me a bit about unicode. Hopefully some of it will stick.

Comment: @drajc: It never sticks the first time for me, but after battling over and over... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator returned by [`str::chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars), which is of type [`str::Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/struct.Chars.html), implements `Clone`. This means that you can create an iterator with the same state as an existing iterator, but then iterates independently, just by calling `.clone()` on the iterator. You can use the clone for lookaheads and advance the original iterator only when you're ready to progress.

`str::Chars` simply wraps `iter::Slice<u8>`, which itself is just a pair of pointers. Thus, cloning a `str::Chars` merely copies these two pointers in a new value, and this doesn't involve any memory allocation. This makes cloning a `str::Chars` very cheap, so don't be shy about it!

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = "чеllo = ==".chars();
    loop {
        let mut s2 = s.clone();
        let c1 = s2.next();
        let c2 = s2.next();
        match (c1, c2) {
            (Some('='), Some('=')) => { s.next(); println!("=="); }
            (Some('='), _        ) => { s.next(); println!("="); }
            (Some(c)  , _        ) => { s.next(); println!("{}", c); }
            (None, _) => break,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is exactly what I was wondering, but my inexperience with Rust made it hard for me to reason about the amount of overhead, and the ownership complications.